# In an HTML page, to delete on the server, is it correct to make a request with the get method?

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I am displaying a list of records on a web page. Put a link to delete for each record. Given that the links only generate Get requests, is there a security issue? Or what is the correct method of requesting to delete the record to the server?

```
<div>
   <p>Record 1<p>
   <a href='server/Page/?handler=deleteHandler&id=1' >Delete Record 1<a/>
<div>
<div>
   <p>Record 2<p>
   <a href='server/Page/?handler=deleteHandler&id=2' >Delete Record 2<a/>
<div>
<div>
   <p>Record 3<p>
   <a href='server/Page/?handler=deleteHandler&id=1' >Delete Record 3<a/>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a *security* issue, but it can be an *issue*.

GET requests are supposed to be [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231.html#section-4.2.1).

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are
> essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does
> not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of
> applying a safe method to a target resource.  Likewise, reasonable
> use of a safe method is not expected to cause any harm, loss of
> property, or unusual burden on the origin server.

There was a case, sadly I can't find documentation for it now, where someone installed a browser plugin to precache links from any webpage they viewed so there would be less of a delay from clicking the link to viewing the page.

This person logged into a web forum to which they had admin access, and the precacher followed all the *delete* links and deleted every post on every page of every thread the admin read.

---

> Or what is the correct method of requesting to delete the record to the server?

Use a button, not a link.

This can be either a submit button that submits a POST form, or a button hooked into Ajax that makes a suitable request (with the POST or DELETE method).

---

That said, you do have a security issue. It just isn't directly related to your use of links. You are vulnerable to CSRF attacks.